# typescript function definition confusion

Tags: typescript

I'm building an mui table and I'm reading the docs to truly understand the code but I'm confused as to what the following function definition means:

```
function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key,
): (
  a: { [key in Key]: number | string },
  b: { [key in Key]: number | string },
) => number {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}
```

Are a and b the arguments? or are order and orderBy? I'm thinking order and orderBy are the arguments you can set by default and a and b are passed whenever the functions initialized, but again I'm not sure.

Comment: `(a: { [key in Key]: number | string },b: { [key in Key]: number | string },) => number` is the return value. Arguments: `(order: Order,orderBy: Key,)`

Comment: usage: `getComparator(order, orderBy)(a, b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That funcution definition uses an anonymous type to define its return type, which is another function so I can understand why you find it confusing.

Perhaps this will make it clearer, here I've moved the return type out into a named type called `Comparator`:

```js
type Comparator<Key extends keyof any> = (
  a: { [key in Key]: number | string },
  b: { [key in Key]: number | string },
) => number;

function getComparator<Key extends keyof any>(
  order: Order,
  orderBy: Key,
): Comparator<Key> {
  return order === 'desc'
    ? (a, b) => descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy)
    : (a, b) => -descendingComparator(a, b, orderBy);
}
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gWzAQwE7OHVAeA0hEKCAD2AgDsATAZygGsC4AzKZckAPigF4oAKAFBRWALigBvKAG0GhAJbko+EAF0x5AK4IARhFRQAPlGrBUCgOZQAvgBohUbWMkyCUBUoJqomnXsPHTC2s7AEoeLh9dVABuAQEmDXIAY2A5OEVzCGB4JDQMLDxXEjIqWllmVnYOQWEsSj0xAHlUetQ7Wpa9ACEQMWVQsRyUdEwcZS5xe1QsjVRFOr9uJagAcnrqJJX7YQB+fmQbBzDuLnWkikoLIbzRvgOHQ4XUHpDtqDE7w+1jrgBaM4uV0Qw3yqE+DygTxesSsQA)

As you can hopefully see more clearly in that example, the arguments of `getComparator` are `order` and `orderBy`. And `getComparator` returns a new function with arguments `a` and `b`.

Comment: Ok so it defines the arguments of its own return function, as well as its own arguments? Did I say that right?

Comment: Yep you've got that right. It's a function that returns another function, so its definition includes what's often referred to as the *call signature* of the function it returns.